# /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope keeps resetting to 1

Tags: kernel, wine

Running Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit.

/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope keeps resetting to 1 if I reboot, despite me changing it to 0 manually. How can I keep ptrace_scope set to a value of 0?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

/proc values are stored in RAM so it isn't persistent. But it read its initial values from a file. You can permanently change the value of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope to 0 by editing the file  `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` and change the line:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1
```

To

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

Comment: Is any security risk attached to setting this permanently?

Comment: Yes, there is some risks. You can view this post for more details [https://askubuntu.com/questions/146160/what-is-the-ptrace-scope-workaround-for-wine-programs-and-are-there-any-risks]

Comment: Well i showns how crazy the security boys have gotten. 
If you run a program under your user id it already can do enough damage.

Answer (score 5):

In case the change doesn't reflect in /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, try doing:

```
echo "0"|sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```